# Can boot Windows but unable to boot any linux

Tags: startup, hardware, troubleshooting

My laptop (Thinkpad W520) suddenly shut down without warning... I tried to reboot, passed grub without issue but, again, shut down during the boot process... I tried recovery mode: same. Live cd and USB, also the same.

Now, where I need to understand what is happening: Windows boots without issue. I was able to run the diagnostics tools from the maker of my laptop and everything was successful. They offer a more complete diagnostic tool but this one is a Linux live CD so it won't boot...

I then try to deactivate everything possible in the BIOS, hoping that it may boot and help me to identify the culprit. No luck there neither...

What could be the problem that prevents Linux to boot but not Windows?

**EDIT**:

I was able to retrieve the logs from windows.

syslog just before a failed boot:

```
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 ModemManager[842]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'Generic' and '1' ports
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 ModemManager[842]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyS0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyS0', unhandled serial type'
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 ModemManager[842]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3': Failed to find primary AT port
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 kernel: [   24.397734] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 kernel: [   24.397737] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 kernel: [   24.397740] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
...
... temperature errors repeated for all cores
...
Jun 19 14:01:33 w520 kernel: [   24.398746] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

Just before initial crash (I think):

```
Jun 19 11:15:01 w520 CRON[16977]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Looks like a thermal shutdown but the diagnostics I did included a CPU stress test and it was successful.

Concerning the mce error, more detail should be available in the mcelog file but this file doesn't exist...

Something else that may be relevant is that, even though I tried to boot many times, only one attempt appears in the log files at 14:00. The first crash was around 11:15.

Comment: What laptop? What Linux? What Windows? The first thing to try would be to re-set BIOS settings to factory defaults. Anything else requires the answers to 3 questions.

Comment: This is a Lenovo Thinkpad W520 "running" Debian 9 and Windows 7. After deactivating everything I reset to default settings. I also updated it from windows.

Comment: Try a completely different OS, i.e. Fedora, Slackware or even FreeBSD or Solaris. You may be stuck on a particularly bugged kernel with Deb9 which just happens to not work with your laptop.

Comment: Based on other recommendations, I tried Fedora with kernel 4,16 and it didn't boot either. I just tried to run the TrueOs install and it was able to boot. I don't know if this really means anything since it was not a full system running but just the installer. Still, the Debian install was not able to boot that far.

Comment: If there is an updated BIOS @ Lenovo, or if you can load the current one, that's worth trying, as something in the flash ROM could have been corrupted due to overheating reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean suddenly shutting down in the form of crashing without an error message? Then I would not rule out a hardware problem - some of them
can get linux to crash, and leave windows in a working state, or the other
way around.

You should look into testing your RAM with Memtest86 (not linux-based as far as I know) which you can download from the internet for free (on some ubuntu version I even saw it preinstalled in the grub menu). You can also boot into windows to see if you can find log entries indicating hardware problems (WHEA errors for example). The other answer suggested looking into the logs from another computer - I would suggest that as well, it could yield useful information for debugging.

Comment: Yes, crashing without error message. I ran Memtest86 (preinstalled on debian too) without issue. 

I'm currently looking to the logs and I posted what seems relevant above.

Comment: You didn't include what distribution and kernel your OS was running - maybe this could be related? https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/68hrw8/possible_fix_for_machine_check_exception_and_cpu/

Comment: I'm running Debian 9 with kernel 4.9. I can't change my kernel however since I can't boot at all...

Comment: It might be worth trying a recent live CD, for example the Ubuntu 18.04 live installer. It ships with a newer kernel (4.15 if I'm correct), and it would be interesting to see if the problem persists there and/or if the logging there gives more details.

Comment: I thought the after your comment. I'm burning the latest stable fedora with kernel 4.16. Also to try with a non-Debian based distribution.

Comment: Exactly the same... I really don't understand how windows can run without issue while Linux distributions are not even able to boot...

Comment: In your logs, the system seems to emit Machine Check Exceptions (MCEs), which are treated by linux as critical errors, that are reported, but cannot be corrected by the system software. If they are deemed critical, the OS just stops executing, which, for example in case of an ECC error in the CPU cache, could prevent further damage like corrupted data. Windows utilizes the hardware differently and is a platform completely different from linux, which might be a reason why the issue does not occur under windows, or why the occuring issue is not treated in the same way

Comment: What you could also try is see if there are CPU temperature readings available in the BIOS of your system. Maybe these differ from what windows reports, and could give a hint.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. There is no temperature in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried that diagnostic CD? If it doesn't work then you can ask Lenovo for assistance. But it might have all the necessary stuff not to  shutdown during bootup. From there you might run whatever diagnostics they offer, as well as check you're OSs' logs for what's wrong in their bootup.

Another option is to attach your hard drive to a running Linux and inspect the logs from there.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that diagnostic CD. I just saw they also have a live USB version. I'll try this one too but I fear it will be the same...

Concerning the Lenovo assistance, it is as awful when a product is out of warranty as it is good when still under warranty... I only have access to their forum now. I'll try that too.

I'm currently trying to find a way to recover the log files. I'll update if I find something useful.

Comment: @Tonio Also check if your BIOS secure bootup option is not set to true. In particular the OS registration with BIOS might cause similar problems.

Comment: I don't have this option in the BIOS. I'm not really familiar with that but I guess it's a UEFI thing. My BIOS is set to work in legacy mode.

Comment: I was able to access the logs. I added some details above.